# Angular Unit Test: How to pass FormGroupDirective in a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to unit test a function which is taking a parameter of type `FormGroupDirective`. I am able to test all logic but cannot understand what should be taken as parameter to call the `resetForm()` function. Below is my code which I am testing.

```html
<form [formGroup]="logForm" #formDirective="ngForm" (submit)="onSave(formDirective)">...</form>
```

```js
onSave(formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
  this._http.save(this.logForm.value).subscribe({
    next: response => {
      this._notification.show({ message: response.message, action: 'SUCCESS', panelClass: 'success' });
      formDirective.resetForm();
      this.logForm.reset();
      this.trailerHeading = 'Trailer';
      this.showAllTrailers = false;
      this.trailerList = [];
    }
  });
}
```

While unit testing I've passed `null` as value while calling `onSave(...)` method. Which is correctly throwing error while executing `formDirective.resetForm()`.

The test case that I wrote is:

```js
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { HttpClientService } from "@service/http-client.service";
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { MaterialModule } from "src/app/material/material.module";
import { TrailerLogComponent } from "./trailer-log.component";

describe('TrailerLogComponent', () => {

    let component: TrailerLogComponent, fixture: ComponentFixture<TrailerLogComponent>,
        _httpService: HttpClientService;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MaterialModule, RouterTestingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
            declarations: [TrailerLogComponent],
            providers: [HttpClientService],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
        }).compileComponents();
        _httpService = TestBed.inject(HttpClientService);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrailerLogComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should save the trailer log form', () => {
        const response: { message: string } = { message: '' };
        spyOn(_httpService, 'save').and.returnValue(of(response));
        component.onSave(null); // what should I pass here??
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.trailerHeading).toEqual('Trailer');
        expect(component.showAllTrailers).toBeFalsy();
        expect(component.trailerList.length).toEqual(0);
    });
});
```

The error is getting thrown when `component.onSave(null)` is called as I am passing null.

What should I pass here instead of NULL to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing unit testing you are not interested in passing a full instance. In general you are fine with a minimal required mock. This means that you need an object that has methods/props that your method is using. To do so you could alter your test body in the following way.

```js
const resetFormFn = jasmine.createSpy('resetFormFn')

component.onSave({ resetForm: restFormFn } as any)

// goes the test
expect(resetFormFn).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Here we create a spy - function which can track its calls. We provide an object with one property `resetForm` which uses the spy. We typecast the object to any as we don't need the whole FormGroupDirective here and don't want TS to complain.

And lastly we verify our spy has been called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an instance of directive

```
component.onSave(new FormGroupDirective());
```

or just an object with mocked function property

```
component.onSave({
 resetForm: () => void 0
});
```

Comment: tried with `new FormGroupDirective()` but got this error - `Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.`

Comment: I dug and saw that it accepts 2 params validators & asyncValidators

Comment: yes, it might want arguments for constructor.
so simpler just pass an object with required function since resetForm() is just called and it doesnt matter what it will return